# How to create something like this?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, line-art, sketching

What kind of style is this?

https://dribbble.com/shots/2836556-Millennium-Falcon-spacecraft-illustration

How would I go about creating something in this style?

Comment: Why not try replicating it yourself in Illustrator first to see how it goes? If you have a specific question/problem you can ask here.

Answer (score 1):

That can simply be drawn in illustrator. I think most of it can be made with the shape tools: circles and rectangles.

Start with the big circle. Make a part for 1 side, copy and paste it, use reflect horizontal and move it to the other side. Use align tops to get them at the same height.

Most of these shapes have the same fill and stroke (outline color and inside color) so once you have the style set all the parts will come out looking the same.

To attach things together, for instance to attach the cockpit to the main body, put them together, select both and hit Pathfinder/join. They will be 1 piece after that and share 1 outline.

Make little circles and change stroke to white for those parts. Align evenly with the align pallet. (make 1 circle, copy and paste the rest)

Draw little stars or type a plus symbol for the stars, arrange them them and adjust sizes with the scale tool.

It would help to take this pic into illustrator, lock it and draw your version right over it, tracing it.